# mysql cursor use dynamic limit

Tags: mysql, cursor

is there a way to use dynamic limit in the cursor?

```
DECLARE cursor_friends CURSOR FOR
SELECT `name` FROM iFriends
LIMIT iLimit, 50;
```

I have read on some forums that mysql cursors don't support dynamic limit in cursors. wondering if there is some alternative for this

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic cursor in stored procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7685588/dynamic-cursor-in-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL cursors cannot use dynamic statements.

Workaround: use [prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) to create a temporary table or a view with LIMIT clause, then open cursor on this new table or view.

Let me ask you a question - why do you need to use cursor? Sometimes it is possible to avoid using cursors.

Comment: actually i want to use it in a stored proc.

Comment: actually i want to use it in a stored proc.
i have page with news, have to get 10 news per page and every news contain a news generator and news receiver {both users have to get their data too from users table}, news contain comments too have to get 10 comments for every news {comments are from users hence have to get details of every commenter}..

i had written a stored proc for above but was unable to use paging logic due to lack of dynamic limit support in cursors.

so, can someone guide me with a good logic to fetch the above mentioned data in  a better way i dont like looping over query