# sql - stored function parameter not recognize in query - (Table 'population.tableName' doesn't exist)

Tags: mysql, sql

I made function which return one random row from database table.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION randomRow(tableName varchar(200)) RETURNS VARCHAR(200)
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE count int;
    declare randomNum int;
    declare row varchar(200);
    declare sum int;
    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT name FROM tableName;
    set count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM names_men);
    set randomNum =  round(RAND() * (count - 0) + 0);
    set sum =0;
    open cur;
    loop1: loop
        If sum = randomNum THEN
            leave loop1;
        end if;
        FETCH cur INTO row;
        set sum = sum+1;
    END LOOP loop1;
RETURN row;
END;

SET @x = randomRow("animals");
select @x;
```

When I call this function sql shows error:

> ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 55: Table 'population.tableName' doesn't exist.

Its because parameter tableName is not recognized in query. How can I handle this situation?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: You cannot pass table names in as parameters.  You need to use dynamic SQL.  However, that depends on the database you are using, so you should tag the question with the right database.

Comment: iam using mysql database

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic cursor in stored procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7685588/dynamic-cursor-in-stored-procedure)